# Git-pull problem

Tags: git, pull

I made a new branch "counterflow" on my local machine and edited my .git/config file to look like:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://host/~/Repositories/CFFC.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "counterflow"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/counterflow
```

CFFC.git is a bare repository. Now I am trying to pull the "counterflow" branch from a different machine. The .git/config file on this machine looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://host/~/Repositories/CFFC.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "counterflow"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/counterflow
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Warning: No merge candidate found because value of config option
         "branch.counterflow.merge" does not match any remote branch fetched.
No changes.
```

Any clues whats going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I figured it. I forgot to create the branch "counterflow" in the bare repository.